# How do you access the user's bearer token in a ServiceStack service?

Tags: servicestack

I have a ServiceStack service which is receiving a bearer token, the bearer token then needs to be passed onto Microsoft Graph for additional API calls from the server side

What is the best way to access this bearer token as a string?

At the moment I am doing my own processing via

```
        var session = SessionAs<AuthUserSession>();

        var identityId = session.UserAuthName;
```

But there does not seem to be a way to access the string bearer token using the Session helpers

Answer (score 0):

The Access Tokens are stored in the `UserAuthDetails` table which you can resolve the `GetUserAuthDetails/Async` APIs from your registered `IAuthRepository`, but if you readily need access to it you can use the [AuthEvents](https://docs.servicestack.net/sessions#auth-events) that's [pre-configured in Auth Enabled templates](https://docs.servicestack.net/auth-repository#extending-userauth-tables) to access it from `IAuthTokens` and populate it on your CustomUserSession or Custom UserAuth table.

Comment: Hi @mythz, my AuthRepository is null as I am not serving tokens, only validating them via my "JwksJwtAuthProviderReader" - is reading the Request.Authorization header directly the next best thing I can do?

Comment: @JanMartin Have you checked `IAuthTokens` in your AuthEvents?